# Regarding "UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled", what is the default value in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, appsettings

```
<appSettings>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Currently, we  have  UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled set to true in the appSettings
(This can be also be defined in global.asax)

We are looking at cleaning up the appSettings and removing configuration that we do not need to explicitly define  (Especially framework stuff), but not sure what it defaults to.

Answer (score 1):

The default value is true, so unobtrusive javascript is enabled by default. You can remove the setting if you wish. And by the way it is the same in ASP.NET MVC 3.